# Check if Array1 length is equal to Array2 length (bash)

Tags: bash

In a for loop I am looking to find out: If `Array1` length matches `Array2` length then `break` the for loop.

Shellcheck throws an error (while the script runs fine)

```
    if [[ "${!Array1[@]}" == "${!Array2[@]}" ]] ; then
            break;
    fi

^-- SC2199: Arrays implicitly concatenate in [[ ]]. Use a loop (or explicit * instead of @).
```

I'm still learning bash and my teacher said "Always verify with Shellcheck" and to "always place conditionals in double [[ ]]" and to "never use * for array length"

The error(s) are removed with the correction

```
    if [ "${!Array1[*]}" == "${!Array2[*]}" ] ; then
            break;
    fi
```

I was wondering what is the best practice here?

Comment: If by length you mean the number of elements, `"${!Array1[@]}"` is wrong.

Comment: Obtain the length of (count of elements in) an array with `"${#array[@]}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is partly correct. The problem is, that you are expanding the array's indicies with th `!` operator, and not the length by using the `#` operator.

Thus a warning about implicit concatenation is issued for both uses of `${array[@]}`, as the list of indicies is `0 1 2 3 ...`. Nevertheless your code is working, as two non associative bash arrays with equal length will have identical index lists `0 1 2 .. N`.

To get rid of the warning, you should replace `${!array[@]}` with `${#array[@]}`. Of course, using `${!array[*]}` will also suppress the warning, but that is definitely not what you want to do here, as you would continue comparing index lists.

For further reading: The author of shellcheck has explained the concatenation issue [here in detail](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2199).

Comment: *two non associative bash arrays with equal length will have identical index lists `0 1 2 .. N`* This is generally not true, as there may be gaps in the used values of indices, e.g. `declare -a a='([0]="a" [1]="b" [10]="c")'` for which `${#a[@]}` evaluates to 3 and `${#a[@]}` is `0 1 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Nyronium's works well and explains the solution perfectly.

I also found a solution that utilities # to check the array length for the condition.

Sorry I did not have this example script before, as I wrote it to test logic afterwards.

Example

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=(1 2 3)
array2=()

echo "array1 length: ${#array1[@]}" #output :3

for i in {1..10} ; do
        echo "array2 length: ${#array2[@]}"
        array2+=("$i")

        #I want to exit when array2 = a length of 3
        if [[ "${#array1[@]}" == "${#array2[@]}" ]] ; then
                echo "exit"
                break
        fi
done

echo "final array1 length: ${#array1[@]} vs array2 length: ${#array1[@]}"
```

Result: final array1 length: 3 vs array2 length: 3